# Need two-way linkage for glossaries

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

This MWE works well, but only in one direction.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{glossaries}
    
    \newglossary*{Nouns}{Things}
    \newglossary*{Symbols}{Math Symbols}
    \makeglossaries%
    
    \newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{
      type=Nouns,
      name=electrolyte,
      description={solution able to conduct electric current}
    }
    \newglossaryentry{pi}{
      type=Symbols,
      name={\ensuremath{\pi}},
      description={ratio of circumference of circle to its diameter},
      sort=pi
    }
    
    \begin{document}
      Some text about \gls{electrolyte} and \gls*{pi}.
      \clearpage
      \printglossaries%
    \end{document}
```

While I've been able to provide two-way linkages in the full code, the linkage provided by the package obscures (at least to me) the way to double up so to speak. Simply put, my goal is to click on the `\gls` target and then to be able to return.

Comment: Use `Alt + left` to return.

Comment: I get caught up in programming and overlook the obvious! Thanks, Ulrike!